# Streaming in Python for scientific data analysis

Tags: python, hadoop, streaming, analysis

I just began using hadoop on a single node cluster on my laptop and I tried to do it in Python which I know better than Java. Apparently streaming is the simplest way to do so without installing any others packages.

Well my question is, when I do a little data analysis with streaming, I had to:

1. Transform my data (matrix, array ... ) into text file which fit in the default input file format for streaming.
2. Re-construct my data in my mapper.py to make explicitly (key, value) pairs and print them out.
3. Read the result in text format and transform then into matrix data so that I could do other things with them.

When you do a wordcount with text file as input, everything looks fine. But how do you handle data structure within streaming then? The way I did seems just unacceptable...

Comment: To mark a problem as solved you must click on the green tick adjacent to the answer you choose. Editing the word "solved" into the question or title does not closed the problem as solved. Please click that tick.

Answer (score 1):

For python and hadoop, please look for `MRjob` package, http://pythonhosted.org/mrjob/

You can write your ouwn encoding-decoding protocol, streaming matrix row as a rownum-values pair, or every element as row:col-value pair and so on.

Either way, hadoop is not the best framework to work with for matrix operations, since its designed for big amounts of non-interrelated data, i.e. when you key-value processing do not depend on other values, or depends in a very limited way.

Comment: I used a cloudera quickstart package in a virtual machine. I'm not sure I'm able to install other packages in Hadoop (I tried Pydoop, but didn't work), but I'll definitly try Mrjob later. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using json as a text format makes for very convenient encoding and decoding.

For example a 4*4 identity matrix on hdfs could be stored as:

```
{"row":3, "values":[0,0,1,0]}
{"row":2, "values":[0,1,0,0]}
{"row":4, "values":[0,0,0,1]}
{"row":1, "values":[1,0,0,0]}
```

In the mapper use `json.loads()` from the json library to parse each line into a python dictionary which is very easy to manipulate. Then return a key followed by more json (use `json.dumps()` to encode a python object as json):

```
1    {"values":[1,0,0,0]}
2    {"values":[0,1,0,0]}
3    {"values":[0,0,1,0]}
4    {"values":[0,0,0,1]}
```

In the reducer use `json.loads()` on the values to create a python dictionary. These could then be easily converted into a numpy array for example.

Comment: great ideal using json. I'll try! Thanks